# Connect Schneider EM6400 to ESP8266 and call REST API

Tags: usb, uart, ttl, rs485, esp8266

I have a Schneider EM6400 meter whose data I need to send to a web-service.
I dont know much about electronics so here it is-

How do I do it? My idea is to use an ESP8266.
But from what I know, the meter sends data from RS485. Hence direct connection is not possible.

Can I use [RS485 to TTL bi-directional Converter](http://www.ebay.in/itm/RS485-to-TTL-bi-directional-Converter-Transceiver-for-8051-AVR-Arduino-PIC-ARM-/262311604787?hash=item3d12fd7233:g:8agAAOSwkZhWTwtS)?

Also, I think the output can be obtained from USB. So, Can I connect that USB to [USB 2.0 to TTL UART Serial Converter](http://www.ebay.in/itm/USB-2-0-to-TTL-UART-Serial-Converter-Adapter-for-Arduino-AVR-ARM-Other-MCU-/321997660683?hash=item4af88e620b:g:Z8cAAOSw5dNWik03) or [FT232RL 3.3V 5V FTDI USB to TTL Converter](http://www.ebay.in/itm/121884236055?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)?

**NOTE:** I know the ESP programing part. Just need to know about the conversion.

Comment: Sure, you can connect a converter, then use another device (computer, raspi, 'duino, cell phone/whatever) to connect the data  to the internet, but without a FAR more specific question, as outloned in the [help], or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I dont understand what I can be more "specific" about. I mentioned what I need to do, all I'm asking whether the conversion will work.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont know much about electronics so here it is-How do I do it?

This isn't a case of connecting a few wires and it will work; it will require programming of the ESP module. If that is not your cup of tea, hire a professional.

> Can I use RS485 to TTL bi-directional Converter?

Yes, that is an option for the electrical connection. IIRC the ESP has only one UART, so you will have some fun when deveoping (sharing that one UART between the meter, downloading, and debug-logging).

> Also, I think the output can be obtained from USB. So, Can I connect that USB to USB 2.0 to TTL UART Serial Converter or FT232RL 3.3V 5V FTDI USB to TTL Converter?

Probably not, the meter will act as a slave and that converter is a slave too. Two slaves don't communicate.

Comment: I am a programmer, I can program ESP module. Just dont know the electronics part, the serial conversion.

Comment: Good! You mean the electrical conversion or the serial data format?

Comment: The serial. I read the meter is uses Modbus RTU protocol with RS485. I need to read that data on ESP.

Comment: RS485 <-> RS232 can be done with an RS485 transceiver. (The module you linked to should be OK.) The rest is the modbus protocol, which you can do in software.